# rfid readers 915 - 917 MHZ?

Tags: rfid

I need to track items in gold jewelry store usig RFID, located in Israel.

I am looking for an RFID reader, which works within 915-917 MHz and matches israeli law.

Comment: Welcome here :-) You don't look for company, you look for hardware. This is on-topic. If you found the hardware, you also found the company, but here you look for the hardware. The goal is to make your question useful also for others, looking for the same hardware. Other close reasons might still apply, as I explained in my MSE answer, be careful. Please read also the MSE comments.